# C# Structure - Access class from external library

Tags: c#, class, dll, structure

I have a question regarding correct way to structure my application. I am a beginner on C# so excuse if I have some basis missing.
I looked on the web(not only stackoverflow) but didn't find any answer, so maybe this is just because I am doing something wrong?

I have a project in which there are several classes to define my objects.

Object1.class.cs

Object2.class.cs
...

Now for some functions, I created class libraries (.dll files) to externalise the code. The idea is if I need to make an update, I just need to replace .dll file, and not all the code.

But I meet a problem when I want to send objects to that class, I think because they are external to the solution?

So I begin to wonder if I do it correctly.

1) Is there a way to send an object from my project to a class I created separately?

2) Is this a good idea to work this way? I mean, I could of course add the library in my project, but in that case I will not have separated .dll files, and all get in a single .exe file.

3) When I need to test my class, I always need to close my project, and open the class to edit it, then come back to my project to test it. Is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your advises

Edit 2.

Simone Cifani perfercly answered to my question :

1) Classes must be externalised

2) Add references to necessary classes in my external libraries

3) Add references to each class and external libraries in my main project

As I don't know how to use Interfaces I will do without it, but I think all will be fine even without.

Comment: What do you mean with "send objects to that class"?

Comment: my object has a list of parameters (int, string, List<OtherObjects>)...
Until now the only way I found is call my library's function makeCalculous(string1,int1,int2...) If there were only 2 or 3 parameters would be fine, but now I begin to have a lot of them(30), so it would be easier to transfer whole object to the function, and not a list of string/int.

Comment: Show us your code.  Specifically the method signatures and how you are calling them.

Comment: You can create a Core project to keep your domain objects and any other common object that can use across DLLs. Then you refer it from main app and other projects (dlls).

Comment: "But I meet a problem when I want to send objects to that class" - what kind of problem? What are you doing and why it is not working?

Comment: `Repere` should be located on a third project (assembly) which is common to your external and base classes. In this way it will be visible to both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common way to externalize part of the code is by using interfaces.

A simple example is:

```
//CalculatorInterface.dll
namespace Calculator.Interface
{
    interface ICalculator
    {
        int DoCalculus(List<object> list);
    }
}

//CalculatorImplementation_1.dll
//  Add a reference to CalculatorInterface.dll
namespace Calculator.Implementation
{
    using Calculator.Interface;

    class CalculatorImplementation_1 : ICalculator
    {
        public int DoCalculus(List<object> list)
        {
            int result = 0;

            foreach (Object obj in list)
            {
                if (obj is int)
                {
                    result += (int)obj;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

//Calculator.dll
//  Add a reference to CalculatorInterface.dll
//  Add a reference to CalculatorImplementation_1.dll (or dynamically load it)
namespace Calculator
{
    using Calculator.Interface;
    using Calculator.Implementation;

    class MyCalculator
    {
        void CalculateSomething()
        {
            List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
            list.Add(1);
            list.Add(2);
            list.Add("SomeString");

            ICalculator calculator = new CalculatorImplementation_1();

            int result = calculator.DoCalculus(list);

            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never used interfaces, but if I understand your proposal(and your comment upper), I may make 3 different projects.
Problem doin like that, is everytime I need to change one of the dll, I must copy it in each of my project's folder?
For example I made a modify in CalculatorInterface.dll, then I need to copy this .dll in the folder where is Calculator.Implementation project, then in calculator.dll project folder?

If so what I need is :

1) Externalise my classes, then mae a .dll file
2) Add references to this .dll in all .dll that use it.
3) Add references to all dlls in my main project

Comment: Also a question, in your example you are using Interfaces, but as much as I understood, I could do it without interfaces. So what is advantage in using interfaces?
Then concerning your comment on my question, doing as you say I could easily send/return to/from my .dll objects, and not just List<string>?

Comment: The advantage of using interfaces is that you can externalize the implementation and change them without doing any change in your main project. You could think an interface as a contract. In my example I suggest 3 different projects because I thought it is more adherent to your needs, but there are other ways to structure the code. Concerning practical aspects, if you are using Visual Studio you only need to add references to the projects, then if you change something in a dll it will copy it for you. Obviously you can send/return to/from your .dll any kind of object.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I think you are right, the only way is to externalize my objects libraries, and I will do so. But having no experience on Interfaces(I read about it but didn't completely understood), I will do without it.
Last question I hope :) In fact I am using visual studio and added references. When I modify a dll project, I always then copy dll to my other folders using it, what you mean is VS automaticaly make it for me?

Comment: I mean that VS automatically copies all dependencies (dlls) to your main project bin folder. If you update one of them, when you build the project it will copy it for you.

Comment: ok didn't know it, thanks for information :) and is there possibility when I debug my mainproject, to directly edit referenced dlls, without quiting the main project?

Comment: VS provides a feature called [Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164926.aspx), but it has some restrictions and not always works

Comment: Just took a look to your link, and this is not what I meant(but it explains why sometimes VS lets me modify my code without stopping debugging) : When I debug my main project, if I need to modify a library, I need to do "Open recent project"->MyLibrary, then I edit my library, then again OpenRecentProject->MyMainProject. What I would like is not to close my project, just stop debugging, modify the library, then launch again debuging, without changing project.

Comment: In your VS Solution you can add as much projects as you want. Then, when you add references choose the solution->projects tab and add from there. Easy but hard to explain in few words, [here is an helpful link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for all your help, in fact just reading your first phrase, I inmediately understood, and now seems so obvious :)

Comment: Excuse me again : I am trying to apply your solution(externalise classes). The problem is I have 8 different classes, that is calling each other. I guess there is no way to do it "easily"? but just in any case, if you had some advise would be welcome, cause I am thinking I may have done it earlier ^^'

Comment: cannot edit last comment... well I see how to do it, it is not easy thing as lot of dependencies from a class to another... I guess I have no choice now, would have needed to do it earlier :)