# C# - externalise classes in separated Class Libraries

Tags: c#, class, dll, structure

Well, first excuse me if this is not the place to do so. This is not really a question, but I got exposed to that problem, and was pretty hard to find necessary information, so I thought would be good to make a subject just for it.
This is in attention to people with a "beginner/average" level in C# like me, so please if you have some comments or corrections to make please you are welcome.

It is around a year I was developping my project, using a lot classes. But I began to meet problems when I wanted to externalise some functions.

Why externalise my functions? In order to make support easier. In fact, creating an external LibraryClass (.dll), if in future I may make some modifies on it, and send an upgrade to customer, I only need to modify, and send that library, and not all the code.
The problem is when I want to use my classes from these libraries : It is just not possible.

Then a stackoverflower (thanks Simone Sifani) gave me the good idea : I may externalize all my classes in different projects(one project for each class).
In my case the thing became a bit difficult because all classes use each other... so I will explain how I proceeded.

1) make obviously a copy of your solution before beginning, so if you do something wrong, delete all then restart(and very good exercise to understand good how these references work, after one or two tries, you will all understand).

2) Add a Project in solution for each class you want to externalize (Right click on solution/Add new project/Class Library), then check directly the version of Framework to have the same version in all solution(in my case .NET Framework 4.6.2). If you don't, you will have no error message but debugging will not work without necessary an explaination.

3) Copy/Paste all the code of the original class in the new corresponding ClassLibrary. Then add the "public" word before each class definition.

```
class Myoldclass
    {
        ...
    }
```

becomes

```
public class Myoldclass
{
    ...
}
```

4) Add references (this is the longest part).

Each class may require different references :
 - To .NET Frameworks
 - To other classes(From now I will not use the word "class" but "Library")

I personally did the following :

4-1) put in commentary all the code that requires to use external libraries, so now you will have only errors regarding references missing on .NET Assemblies and some "unexisting functions(the ones I just put in commentary).
I also advise you to take a piece of paper, in order to write for each library, the list of references needed.

4-2) Add all references to necessary .NET Assemblies (for me was the longest part of the job). After that, you may have only errors regarding non existing functions.

4-3) Begin to compile all of your libraries that don't need to use any external library. It will then generate a .dll file in its directory (bin\debug directory). I will call it **Library1**

4-4) In all libraries that need to use **Library1**, add a reference to the libraries(Project/Add/Reference/Projects->Library1.dll file). So now all the code requiring Library1 may work correctly.(I will call that one **Library2**)

4-5) Once you think **Library2** has references to all necessaries libraries, you can uncomment your code. For this I have two solutions : Just make Ctrl+Z until the code comes back to step 3. Inconvenient is sometimes VS found errors where there are not so you need to restart it, and so coming back is impossible.
In my case, I just opened my old classes, and overwrite all the code of my library, rewrite the "public" at class definition... and then start debugging to generate the Library2.dll file

4-6) Continue so on until all libraries get all references ok(that's why it is important to write on a paper, so by elimination, you will first debug the libraries having few references needed, and finish with the most difficult ones).

4-7) On your main project, add references to all previously generated dlls.

That's all, after it for my part my project is working as before(still have some problems to read Application parameters but I am on it). I have 13 Class Library projects in my solution, that I can debug separately, and everybody can use anybody :)

Hope that post will be useful to somebody, and if stackoverflowers want to help/correct I will try to keep it updated.

Comment: *"The problem is when I want to use my classes from these libraries : It is just not possible"* -- What's not possible about using a class from a library?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you have error messages or something like that? Is this a "How to use class libraries" instead of a question? I'm pretty confused

Comment: maybe I didn't explain well, I have no more problem, but it took long to solve it, that's why I made that post.
This is following this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792726/c-sharp-structure-access-class-from-external-library?noredirect=1#comment78546114_45792726

Comment: Ok i got it. I'm sorry, but that does not belong on StackOverflow. It is not a question but a tutorial. I appreciate your efforts, but this belongs onto a blog post or something like that and not on so.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, well yes, if I make an external class library, I may not be able to use classes of main project. And in general, if like in my case you have a big project whose classes were not externalized, and you want to do it, it is a hard thing(maybe not for you, but for me it took two days to do it...)

Comment: understood Tobias, I believed this would be useful, cause in my case I could find absolutely nothing as tutorial... Where do you think I could post it? I have no right to post it in "Documentation" part.

Comment: 4.4 - Why not to use project references? VS will copy all dependencies automatically. You just need to have all projects (Library1, LibraryN, MainProject) in your solution

Comment: vianov what do you mean? there was a way to add all references automaticaly?In fact I had all in the same solution, but didn't know there was a way to do it in automatic

Comment: @Siegfried.V References -> Projects (insted of Browse) -> Solution tab. You see will entire list of the projects in your solution.

Comment: @vianov I see, if I understand it shows all libraries of my project... so in fact it is quicker than always browse... thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

What is the point of creating as much projects? In most cases I do need a "Common" library and sometimes a library for DTO. Anyhow the main reason to move out those classes into a separate project is to minimize **dependencies** and to avoid polluting some of your layers...

In general I use these **layers**/projects:
 - domain classes and domain logic with domain services - here I define also interfaces, which get's implemented inside service layer
 - DAL (which is actually an ORM) - so here due mapping (or due domain classes being entities) we got a dependency on the domain classes (project)
 - service layer - depending on both of the 2 projects above
 - presentation (application) layer - where all your projects are referenced...

Mostly I do have a **solution with 6-15 projects**: 4 of them are based on the layers described above, but I do got additional ones, like domain events, domain event dispatcher (for the given DI used in the project), special libraries like HTML/PDF generation or email sending (with custom logic/templates), HttpClient libraries (spacial library to create and set up chain of handlers to do: auto-login, auto retry on HTTP 401, auto-retry on some errors or logging)...

**So in short:** as you see, most projects I add do have a function to fulfill. They're not class based. **And there's a "polluted" project with a lot of extension and utility classes**, where I do try to keep things tidy by trying to keep the classes in folders, giving them meaningful names...

In your case, if those class libraries are really re-usable, i'd possibly create them as a separate project and NuGet's. **But if reuse is the goal, you need to strictly hold on some SOLID rules, otherwise a change in those classes for some feature in project A can easily break your business logic in project B.**

Comment: Maybe at a hyperlink at your "SOLID" to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: thanks for answer, first excuse me but many of your terms are unknown to me(will try to read some documentation on it). Then yes I need to have this quantity of dlls. In my case I make a software for metal construction, one .dll for each machine post-processor, one dll for different kind of structure with its properties, functions... and I want a separate .dll file for each of them because if tomorrow I make an upgrade for one model of machine, I just send the dll to my customer, and not all solution.

Comment: Thanks for SOLID link, I read it and looks interesting, will look for some tutorials on it

Comment: A lot of DLL in your case might be appropiate, but if one DLL = 1 machine, then try to create a Common.DLL and link that one to the machine related DLL, then just be cautious when updating anything in the Common (see single responsibility and especially open-closed approaches from solid). Anyhow, the detail on DLLs (why so many) was a good one. And again, you might have all machine related in 1 DLL and all your client would get 1 DLL (if it's possible) 10kb or 300kb it does not matters nowadays :D